# Subtracting a list of tuples from a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have 2 datasets, one having 40 cases, another with only 20. I have made a much smaller version for ease of explanation.

```
dataset1 = [(1.5, 2.4), (-7.9, 3.5), (6.3, 6.2), (8.3, 4.1), (4.1, 4.2)]
dataset2 = [(2.9, 3.0), (4.3, 2.9)]
```

The idea of the program is to calculate the Euclidian distance between the point in dataset2[0] (2.9, 3.0) to **all** points in dataset1, and then the same process for dataset2[1] (4.3, 2.9), comparing to **all** points in dataset1.

I want to create this program by use of my own coding, rather than importing external packages. I have tried two formulas below:

Attempt 1 (gives TypeError: unsupported operand type for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'):

```
def distance_calculate(dataset1, dataset2):
    distance = 0
    for i in range(len(point1)):
        # subtracting x-coord then summing with difference of y-coord
        distance += (dataset1[i] - dataset2[i])**2
    return distance**0.5
```

Attempt 2 (gives IndexError: list index out of range):

```
def distance_calculate(dataset1, dataset2):
    distance = 0
    for i in range(len(dataset1)):
        # selecting 0th coordinate for both datasets, and 1st coordinate for both datasets
        distance += (dataset1[i][0] - dataset2[i][0])**2 + (dataset1[i][1] - dataset2[i][1])**2
    return distance**0.5
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, either adjusting above method or if I am missing something completely!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?  Your examples do not work as you use i on dataset2 but length of dataset1.  You have to iterate on them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to define a function to calculate euclidean distance. Then you can loop over each point in the following way:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
>>> dataset1 = [(1.5, 2.4), (-7.9, 3.5), (6.3, 6.2), (8.3, 4.1), (4.1, 4,2)]
>>> dataset2 = [(2.9, 3.0), (4.3, 2.9)]
>>> def euclidean_distance(p1, p2):
...     distance = [(i - j) ** 2 for i, j in zip(p1, p2)]
...     return sum(distance) ** 0.5
... 
>>> all_in_list = [euclidean_distance(p1, p2) for p2 in dataset2 for p1 in dataset1]
>>> all_in_list
[1.5231546211727816, 10.811567878897122, 4.669047011971501, 5.510898293381942, 1.5620499351813306, 2.8442925306655784, 12.214745187681975, 3.858756276314948, 4.17612260356422, 1.118033988749895]
>>> all_in_dict = {'{}_{}'.format(j, i) : euclidean_distance(p1, p2) for j, p2 in enumerate(dataset2) for i, p1 in enumerate(dataset1)}
>>> all_in_dict
{'0_0': 1.5231546211727816, '0_1': 10.811567878897122, '0_2': 4.669047011971501, '0_3': 5.510898293381942, '0_4': 1.5620499351813306, '1_0': 2.8442925306655784, '1_1': 12.214745187681975, '1_2': 3.858756276314948, '1_3': 4.17612260356422, '1_4': 1.118033988749895}
```

Please note that this code doesn't use any external libraries as you expect.

Comment: Good job. It would be easier to read without the (repl) prompts.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us what the output should look like.  Here is a version using `map()` that returns the values as a list of lists:

```
dataset1 = [(1.5, 2.4), (-7.9, 3.5), (6.3, 6.2), (8.3, 4.1), (4.1, 4.2)]
dataset2 = [(2.9, 3.0), (4.3, 2.9)]


def distance(p1, p2):
    return (p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2


def subtract(d1, d2):
    return list(map(
        lambda p1: list(map(
            lambda p2: distance(p1, p2),
            d2
        )),
        d1
    ))


print(subtract(dataset1, dataset2))
```

and the (prettified) result:

```
[
   [2.32, 8.09],
   [116.89000000000001, 149.2],
   [21.8, 14.890000000000002]
   [30.370000000000005, 17.440000000000005],
   [2.88, 1.7300000000000006]
]
```

If you want the other shape, flip the map order.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataset1 = [(1.5, 2.4), (-7.9, 3.5), (6.3, 6.2), (8.3, 4.1), (4.1, 4,2)]
dataset2 = [(2.9, 3.0), (4.3, 2.9)]

def dist_func(dataset1,dataset2):
  dist = {}
  for pt1 in dataset1:
    for pt2 in dataset1:
      dist[(pt1,pt2)] = ((pt1[0]-pt2[0])**2+(pt1[1]-pt2[1])**2)**0.5
  return dist
# Usage 
dist_d1_d2 = dist_func(dataset1,dataset2)
```

Comment: how would i write this into a function, so if i have more datasets, I don't have to re-type this each time? at the moment, it only writes as a NoneType object if i put it as a function

Comment: Updated. I defined a dist_func which can be recycled.